# Qual è il significato di "slittare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te*, di Paola Mastrocola, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Ancora peggio l'esame successivo. Fil non lo passa. Bocciato. E no ne vuol parlare, *slitta*. Chiuso.

Ho cercato il significato del verbo "slittare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il suo significato nel brano precedente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Più avanti nel libro, questo stesso verbo appare in un contesto simile, in questa frase:

> Giuliana gli fece qualche timida domanda su Fil ma il Duca, sempre molto gentilmente, *slittava* su altri argomenti, che perlopiú la riguardavano.

Comment: Un altro uso peculiare dell'autrice. Più comune sarebbe *sorvola*.

Comment: ...o anche “glissa”.

Answer (score 3):

***[Slittare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/slittare.php),***  in senso figurato viene usato per indicare  un modo per evitare qualcosa (una deviazione), in questo caso di  parlare dell'esame non passato. Più comunemente si direbbe  "cambiare discorso".

> - (estens.)  Scivolare su una superficie viscida o gelata o incoerente per improvvisa mancanza di attrito, spec. riferito ad autoveicoli: la macchina è slittata in curva a causa della pioggia; la moto ha slittato sul ghiaccio
> - fig. ***Deviare da un principio, da una linea di condotta,***  spec. in politica: partiti di centro che slittano a sinistra, a destra